# Using insert with condition on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert value to 'ta' and 'tb'(int) column with some condition. I have this controller.

```
public function save()
{
$book = new Book;

$ta = DB::select('SELECT MAX(ta) from book');
if ($ta == 0) { 
        DB :: insert('insert into book (ta, tb) values (?, ?)', array(1, 1));
    }else{
        $tb = DB :: select('select max(tb) from book where ta = ?', array('$ta'));
        if ($tb <= 20) {
            DB :: insert('insert into book (ta, tb) values (ta=?, tb=?)', array('$ta', '$tb' + 1));
        }else{
            DB :: insert('insert into book (ta, tb) values (ta=?, tb=?)', array('$ta' + 1, 1));
        }
    }
$book->ta = $ta;
$book->tb = $tb;
$book->save();
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I wrote the condition in that controller and the result is it insert twice and the column is 0

Comment: Then please show that exact code you have. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason it inserts twice is you make an `DB::insert()` and also create a new book using `$book->save()`

This should work better:

```
$book = new Book;
$ta = DB::table('book')->selectRaw('MAX(ta) AS ta')->first()->ta;
if($ta == 0){
    $book->ta = 1;
    $book->tb = 1;
}
else {
    $tb = DB::table('book')->selectRaw('MAX(tb) AS tb')
            ->where('ta', $ta)->first()->tb;
    if($tb <= 20){
        $book->ta = $ta;
        $book->tb = $tb + 1;
    }
    else {
        $book->ta = $ta + 1;
        $book->tb = 1;
    }
}
$book->save();
```